# How to clean application cache inside expo (android/ios) application

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching

I was searching for  an opportunity to clean application cache inside my app , but all  that I`d found was how to clean project cache  that actually didn`t satisfy my needs. Maby you guys had ever encountered such an issue  and can suggest me  a package for expo or build-in feature , which I`m missing ?

Comment: its just not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I just want to clean application cache  inside my application